# What is the best way to integrate TFS version control

Tags: xcode, version-control, tfs

Working on implementing TFS throughout our organization.  It is easy to integrate with `.NET` projects and any platform that uses Eclipse or a derivative of Eclipse for editing.
What's the best way to use TFS version control with Xcode (now that I find out we need to write some iPhone apps)?

Comment: I have the same problem: I need to use XCode with Team foundation server. I notice this question is a bit old, and some answers are outdated. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391594/has-anyone-here-integrated-team-explorer-everywhere-with-xcode

Answer (score 12):

Xcode integration is something that we at [Teamprise](http://www.teamprise.com) have been looking into a lot. One of the main problems for us is that Apple does not provide a version control API that we can hook into to add a new version control system to Xcode - for integrated version control it is either the systems that Apple provide access to or nothing at the moment.

That said, we do have a number of customers who develop in Xcode for TFS.  They either use [Teamprise Explorer](http://www.teamprise.com/products/explorer/) (which is a standalone GUI client to TFS compiled as a Universal Binary) or they have macros inside Xcode that perform basic check-out and get operations in-conjunction with the [TFS command line (tf)](http://www.teamprise.com/products/clc/).  It's obviously not the ideal experience but acceptable for them.  The stand-alone GUI has the advantage that you can do all the work item tracking stuff there as well and integrate this with your check-ins.

Sorry if this is a very "marketing" type answer - just trying to let you know what our current customers do with Xcode.  If you want more details around the macro approach then let me know.

Hope that helps,

Martin.

Comment: Thanks Martin - I would love to hear more about the macro approach.

Answer (score 4):

Few week earlier announced [Git-tf](http://gittf.codeplex.com/) by codeplex could do the job.

Comment: This is the link to the tutorial on how to do it: http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/code/use-git-and-xcode-with-tfs/

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use the Team Foundation System client under Windows in VMWare, and check out (or whatever TFS calls it) your sources to a directory on your Mac that's shared with the virtual machine.  It also looks like [Teamprise](http://www.teamprise.com/) has a Team Foundation client for Mac OS X built atop Eclipse that would be worth looking into.

That said, I'd very strongly encourage you to use a **natively** cross-platform source code management system like Subversion or Perforce instead of a platform-specific silo like Team Foundation System for your company's soruce code, especially since you're going to be doing multi-platform development.

While you're not likely to share code between a .NET application and an iPhone application, having full cross-platform access to things like design documents can be really important.  Mac OS X 10.5 and later include Subversion, Perforce is readily available, and both Perforce and Subversion are natively supported by the Xcode IDE.  Subversion in particular is also more likely to be familiar to experienced Mac and iPhone developers you might bring onto your projects as you ramp up.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps SVNBridge will do the trick, it's an open source used at CodePlex (Microsoft's Open Source Hosting). Check it out here: http://www.codeplex.com/SvnBridge

I have limited experience with it other than using it briefly to connect to CodePlex.

Comment: Is SVNBridge available on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this links, its raeally helpful:

https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/cross-platform/share-your-xcode-projects-vs

After that Check-in your existing xCode project code into TFS

On your Mac, download and extract [www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30474](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30474). I placed it in `/users/{myuseraccount}/git-tf`

Open Terminal and run the following commands

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:/git_t
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/":$PATH
export PATH="/Users/{myuseraccount}//Git-Tf/":$PATH
```

change the working directory to your xCode project folder:

e.g.: `cd “/users/{myuseraccount}/documents/xCode Projects/testproject1/”`

In terminal fire commond:

```
- git remote add origin url//companyName.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/xyz
```

and than

```
git push -u origin --all
```

It'll directly push your project into Visual studio TFS server..!!!!

Comment: It looks like they've iterated and expanded on this a bit as well. http://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/share-your-xcode-projects-vs

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with this is that Xcode only runs on OS X and TFS client tools only run on Windows.  If you're host operating system in OS X and you have a Windows virtual environment running locally (like Parallels or VMFusion) then you could use Team Explorer or the command-line tools to work with the repository.

But this is a lot of work just to use a really dated version control system. If you don't have to use TFS I would probably use SVN or something else with native OS X support.