# Using Team Foundation Server in Xcode

Tags: xcode, tfs

Has anyone integrated Team Foundation Server in XCode?

I am migrating from Git to TFS.

How can this be done?

Are there any useful tutorials or articles on the matter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to integrate TFS version control with Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70313/what-is-the-best-way-to-integrate-tfs-version-control-with-xcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What is the best way to integrate TFS version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70313/what-is-the-best-way-to-integrate-tfs-version-control-with-xcode)

http://www.compsoft.co.uk/Blog/2010/03/using-team-foundation-server-tfs-with.html

Comment: thanks for sharing the links, I ve already been to those resources. First one quite ok but 2nd one I found SVNBridge kinda hacky and not so trustworthy and it could break at any time. Looking for Teamprise guys to come up with something for XCode as they have already a version with Eclipse in Mac (which I have already tried).

Comment: Although since the original StackOverflow question was answered Teamprise has been acquired by Microsoft, it remains the best guidance. Apple has yet to provide any API for integrating version control tools into Xcode beyond what they provide out of the box (which changes without warning) and so the best guidance is to use the `tf` command line client alongside Xcode.  That said, the number of third party tools such as `svnbridge` or `git-tfs` continue to grow and mature, and may be interesting solutions, though I cannot vouch for those.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft announced and is working on a git extension called [Git-TF](http://gittf.codeplex.com/), which is cross-platform. As of this writing it's still beta but I guess it could already help you.

Comment: Thanks @sergiopereira !! I will certainly look into that.

Comment: Yeah, there's a nice tutorial now http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/code/use-git-and-xcode-with-tfs/